# bucketing with QuantileDiscretizer using groupBy function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, quantile

I have a large dataset like so:

```
| SEQ_ID|RESULT|
+-------+------+
|3462099|239.52|
|3462099|239.66|
|3462099|239.63|
|3462099|239.64|
|3462099|239.57|
|3462099|239.58|
|3462099|239.53|
|3462099|239.66|
|3462099|239.63|
|3462099|239.52|
|3462099|239.58|
|3462099|239.52|
|3462099|239.64|
|3462099|239.71|
|3462099|239.64|
|3462099|239.65|
|3462099|239.54|
|3462099| 239.6|
|3462099|239.56|
|3462099|239.67|
```

The `RESULT` column is grouped by `SEQ_ID` column.
I want to bucket/bin the `RESULT` based on the counts of each group. After applying some aggregations, I have a data frame with the number of buckets that each `SEQ_ID` must be binned by.  like so:

```
| SEQ_ID|num_buckets|
+-------+----------+
|3760290|        12|
|3462099|         5|
|3462099|         5|
|3760290|        13|
|3462099|        13|
|3760288|        10|
|3760288|         5|
|3461201|         6|
|3760288|        13|
|3718665|        18|
```

So for example, this tells me that the `RESULT` values that belong to the 3760290 `SEQ_ID` must be binned in 12 buckets.

For a single group, I would `collect()` the `num_buckets` value and do:

```
discretizer = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=num_buckets, inputCol='RESULT', outputCol='buckets')
df_binned=discretizer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

I understand that when using `QuantileDiscretizer`, each group would result in a separate dataframe, I can then union them all.
But how can I use `QuantileDiscretizer` to bin the various groups without using a `for` loop?